# QGIS standalone application, problem with prefix path

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ubuntu, qgis-3, pycharm

I am trying to create a standalone application of QGIS in PyCharm. My code is:

```
app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.setPrefixPath("usr/lib/qgis/plugins", True)
app.initQgis()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setWindowTitle('Aeee')
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=epsg:4326', 'MyLine' ,"memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
linstr = QgsFeature()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt("LINESTRING (1 1, 10 15, 40 35)")
linstr.setGeometry(geom)
pr.addFeatures([linstr])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayers([layer])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
canvas.freeze(True)
canvas.show()
canvas.refresh()
canvas.freeze(False)
canvas.repaint()
exitcode = app._exec()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

And the error I get is:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-professional', please create it with 0700 permissions.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-professional', please create it with 0700 permissions.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I supposed this problem is because of the application that is trying to access the qgis path and that it having a problem with privileges. My first clue is to change the folder permissions and ownership, but because I am new to Ubuntu and PyQGIS, I asked this question.

Comment: Have you checked these [tips for setting the prefix path on GNU/Linux and Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972)?

Comment: You will find your qgis Path most likely under `/usr/bin/qgis`. And if you are running this standalone outside of qgis, then you can't use the `MapCanvas` Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artwokr21's answer has been approved. I just want to add some information for Ubuntu user

For Windows:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

For Ubuntu (based on [this page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/51131)):

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

Comment: For macOS : QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)

Answer (score 2):

The prefix path needs to point to the root install directory of QGIS.  For example, for windows it may look like this (for v2.18):

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18", True) # not sure what Ubuntu path is
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```