# Running Standalone PyQGIS Script with Multiprocessing?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, parallel-processing

Is it possible to run a standalone PyQGIS script using multiprocessing for better performance?

I'm creating 1,800 rendered map images and would like to run it across 4 processes to speed it up.

If I try to instantiate 4 QgsApplication objects using the following code (one in each process) - they fail silently (i.e. nothing happens and no CPU/hard drive/memory is being used).

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
```

If I instantiate it once and then run the 4 processes - I get a "QgsApplication couldn't be pickled" error.

The code uses Python's *multiprocessing* module to create the parallel processes; using *pool.imap_unordered*

I'm using QGIS 3.8.2 and Python 3.7.3 on a Mac with MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave).

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330255/no-output-in-pyqgis-standalone-script-running-distance-matrix/330801#330801

Comment: Good to know it can be done using bash scripts, however I want to keep in all in a single Python script for simplicity.