# Standalone Python application from QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, standalone

I am trying to run the script generated by my graphical modeller through QGIS script. But I get the following error.

```py
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/')
#sys.path.append('usr/lib/qgis/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import processing
#processing.initialize()

processing.run('script:AppPointsToGrid',            
{'inputdatapoints':'file:///home/vinura/Documents/L900_10000.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude&crs=EPSG:4244&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no','Output':'/home/vinura/Documents/4.geojson'})

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

Error

```py
python3 Script2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script2.py", line 15, in <module>
    processing.run("script:PointsToGrid", {'inputdatapoints':'file:///home/vinura/Documents/L900_10000.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude&crs=EPSG:4244&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no','Output':'/home/vinura/Documents/4.geojson'})
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 125, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm script:PointsToGrid not found
```

Simply, the script doesn't get the `script:PointsToGrid` I made using graphical modeller.

Comment: Your script seems to be correct. can you try running `from qgis.core import QgsApplication

for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print("{}:{} --> {}".format(alg.provider().name(), alg.name(), alg.displayName()))` as suggested [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#processing-algorithms). It should give you a list of available processing algorithms, check that your script is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. It is not obvious, but you need to copy your script algorithms to a specific folder to make your standalone script able to run them.

You can easily see where your script algorithms should be located by adding a couple of lines to your standalone script:

```py
from processing.script import ScriptUtils
print("Folder for script algorithms:", ScriptUtils.scriptsFolders())
```

Once you copy your script algorithms there, run again your standalone script and it should be able to run them.

---

**NOTE:** If your script algorithm makes use of other algorithms not installed by default by Processing, you need to add them. See [Using QGIS3 Processing algorithms from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/4972) for an example to make Native C++ algorithms available for your standalone script.

**Example**

Here is a sample script that you can take as a reference (adjust paths to your own QGIS location):

```py
import sys

from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/docs/dev/qgis/QGIS/build_20190918/output', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/QGIS/build_20190918/output/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

from processing.script import ScriptUtils
print("[INFO] Folder for script algorithms:", ScriptUtils.scriptsFolders())
print("[INFO] Script algorithms available:", 
    [s.displayName() for s in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().providerById("script").algorithms()])

params = {'inputlayer':'/geodata/points.shp',
          'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
res = processing.run("script:my_model", params)

output_layer = res['OUTPUT']  # Access your output layer
print(output_layer.featureCount())
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to import my CSV file first and convert it to a vector then feed it to the script. Anyway THANK YOU !!!!!