# Reprojecting raster (GeoTIFF) using PyQGIS in standalone script

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, pyqgis-3, gdalwarp

I'm trying to reproject a GeoTIFF file within a PyQGIS standalone script.

Using QGIS 3.14 the steps would be:

[image]

resulting in the following process history and the output_raster.tiff being successfully created:

> processing.run("gdal:warpreproject",
> {'INPUT':'C:/Projects/PythonScripts/qgis_python/input/input_raster.tif','SOURCE_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2051'),'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'C:/Projects/PythonScripts/qgis_python/output/output_raster.tif'})

**However**

Running the exact same command in a standalone python script does not create the output file even though it runs without any errors.

My guess is that it has something to do with a conflicting GDAL because I receive the following error reprojecting a raster directly with GDAL:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

input_raster = gdal.Open(r'C:/Projects/PythonScripts/qgis_python/input/input_raster.tif')

gdal.Warp(r'C:\Projects\PythonScripts\qgis_python\output\output_raster.tiff', input_raster, format = 'GTiff', dstSRS="EPSG:4326")
```

*Error:*

> TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type
> 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'

and if I import GDAL befor `qgis.core`, then It can't find the DLL for `qgis._core import *`

**Full Script**

```py
import os

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.14\\apps\\Qt5\\plugins'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = '/home/server/anaconda3/share/gdal'

from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication,
     QgsProcessingFeedback,
     QgsVectorLayer,
     QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.14\\apps\\qgis\\', True)

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.14\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())


reproject_params = {'INPUT':'input/input_raster.tif',
                'SOURCE_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2051'),
                'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
                'RESAMPLING':0,
                'NODATA':None,
                'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,
                'OPTIONS':'',
                'DATA_TYPE':0,
                'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
                'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
                'MULTITHREADING':False,
                'EXTRA':'',
                'OUTPUT':'output/output_raster.tif'}

processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", reproject_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works in QGIS interface then I recommend you copy the command from here:
[image: warp/qgis]

You can then use it in a standalone Python script like that:

```
import os
cmd = 'gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:2180 -t_srs EPSG:2180 -r near -of GTiff {srcPath} {outPath}'\
    .format(srcPath='/home/lpowalka/Documents/dane/finalResults/fax3.tif', outPath='/home/lpowalka/Documents/dane/finalResults/fax3_warped.tif')
os.system(cmd)
```

This way you avoid the complexity of deploying a PyQGIS script or using GDAL Python bindings which both essentially lead to executing this command anyway.

Comment: Thank you Leon. In my case your answer also only works until I "Import processing". After importing processing it raises the error "ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `EPSG:2051' to `EPSG:4326'", also I would like to chain events which looks simpler to do using PyQGIS and memory layers, therefore need to import processing.