# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterDefinitions'

Tags: pyqgis, dissolve, pycharm, attributeerror

I'm trying write simple code line in PyQgis in PyCharm, have already set environment in PyCharm and seems to be working fine because I can iterate through f.i fields in vector layer proceed with success simpler operations.

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
import processing

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer(r'E:\Folder\layer.shp','','ogr')
out_fn =r'E:\Folder\out_layer.shp'
dissolve_field = ['_test_field']

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:dissolve',
                             {'INPUT':polygonLayer,
                              'FIELD':dissolve_field,
                              'OUTPUT':out_fn})
```

After running this few lines i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3427, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-35a681b9a5e0>", line 4, in <module>
    'OUTPUT':out_fn})
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 138, in runAndLoadResults
    for param in alg.parameterDefinitions():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterDefinitions'
```

Software set:
Pycharm 2020.3.5;
QGIS 3.16, installed via OSGEO4W

Could you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the processing module in a standalone script. You are missing some code to initialize a `QgsApplication` instance, as well as importing and initializing the processing module. Please try the example below for running QGIS processing algorithms in a standalone script which I have tested with my own file paths.
Also, you should use `processing.run()` instead of `runAndLoadResults()` since you are not using QGIS gui.

```py
import sys

from qgis.core import QgsApplication 

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

input = 'E:\\Folder\\layer.shp'
output = 'E:\\Folder\\out_layer.shp'
dissolve_field = '_test_field'

processing.run("gdal:dissolve", {'INPUT':input,
                'FIELD':dissolve_field,
                'OUTPUT':output})
```