# Using custom Processing algorithm from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, standalone

How can I run a custom algorithm using `processing.run` ?

I've extended a QgsProcessingAlgorithm following [qgis docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).

I've managed to run a native algorithm in a standalone PyQGIS script following
[Using QGIS3 Processing algorithms from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937#279937)

`QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()` does not show my algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [Using QGIS3 Processing algorithms from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui), you need at least 2 new files:

1. An algorithm provider (`example_algorithm_provider.py`, see [sample provider](https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/blob/master/pyqgis_custom_processing_algorithm_standalone/example_algorithm_provider.py)), which helps you register your algorithm, and
2. Your Processing algorithm (`example_processing_algorithm.py`, see [sample algorithm](https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/blob/master/pyqgis_custom_processing_algorithm_standalone/example_processing_algorithm.py)), where you define the algorithm logic.

The PyQGIS standalone script would be like this:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/docs/dev/qgis/core/QGIS/build_master/output', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/core/QGIS/build_master/output/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

# Add our own algorithm provider
from example_algorithm_provider import ExampleAlgorithmProvider
provider = ExampleAlgorithmProvider()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(provider)

# Run our custom algorithm
layer = QgsVectorLayer("/docs/geodata/bogota/ideca/Loca.shp", "layer", "ogr")
params = {'INPUT': layer}
print("RESULT:", processing.run("my_provider:my_algorithm", params)['OUTPUT'])
```

---

Notes:

1. After initializing Processing, we add our own algorithm provider using  `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(provider)`.
2. You can see a full example (i.e., this PyQGIS standalone script, the `example_algorithm_provider.py` and the `example_processing_algorithm.py`) at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/tree/master/pyqgis_custom_processing_algorithm_standalone