# Add a Python provider for my own scripts (and then use them in a PyQGIS standalone script)

Tags: pyqgis

I try to add my own Provider, to be able to use existing custom scripts in QGIS in a standalone script. I followed the explanations from [**here**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408684/using-custom-processing-algorithm-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui) and created my own provider.

If I run the code below, I can print the natives algs (SAGA, GRASS ...).

But if I uncomment the line `QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(provider)`, I have a Python error (`exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`).

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis import *

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.28.1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import *
Processing.initialize()

# DEFINE MY CUSTOM PROVIDER
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Georges\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\processing\\scripts')
from _provider import MyProvider
provider = MyProvider()

# ADD MY CUSTOM PROVIDER
# QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(provider)

for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    print("{}:{} --> {}".format(alg.provider().name(), alg.name(), alg.displayName()))
```

My custom provider is just near my custom scripts, and like that:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingProvider

import Commune_test_model_v4

class MyProvider(QgsProcessingProvider):

    def loadAlgorithms(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.addAlgorithm(Commune_test_model_v4())

    def id(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Used for identifying the provider.

        This string should be a unique, short, character only string,
        eg "qgis" or "gdal". This string should not be localised.
        """
        return 'my_provider'

    def name(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This string should be as short as possible (e.g. "Lastools", not
        "Lastools version 1.0.1 64-bit") and localised.
        """
        return self.tr('My Provider')

    def icon(self):
        """Should return a QIcon which is used for your provider inside
        the Processing toolbox.
        """
        return QgsProcessingProvider.icon(self)
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In my custom provider, instead of:

```
import MyClass
```

I do:

```
from MyFile import MyClass
```

It works, exactly as described in the [great example](https://github.com/gacarrillor/pyqgis_scripts/tree/master/pyqgis_custom_processing_algorithm_standalone) of gacarrillor.