# Accessing model using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I've tried various ways to acccess my *.model3 file using PyQGIS libs as standalone script.

I can access and run my model from script stored inside QGIS.

```
processing.run('model:my_model_name', params)
```

Is this even achievable outside of QGIS?

How can I extend algorithms/models list when running standalone scripts?

Should I export my model to python and then follow instructions specified at [Using custom Processing algorithm from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408684/using-custom-processing-algorithm-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui) ?