# PyQGIS - Algorythm not found

Tags: algorithm

I want to use the "Networks" extension on PyQGIS. This is correctly installed on QGIS 3.28 (QGIS installed with OSGeo4W) and works on the application.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use it on PyQGIS. The error

> QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm Networks:update_field not found

systematically appears.

For exemple, i want to add a column with this extension (algorythme "update_field").

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
from qgis.core import *

 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.extend(['C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/python/plugins/processing', 
                    'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/python', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/plugins'])
 

from qgis.analysis import *
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

Processing.initialize()  # needed to be able to use the functions afterwards
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

path = f"C:/WAMP/www/CALCULATEUR_ITINERAIRE/RESEAU/"
outputs = {}

alg_params = {
    'EXISTANT': 'Longueur',#name of the column to add
    'FILTRE': '',
    'FORMULE': '$length',
    'INPUT': path + "data/road.gpkg",
    'OUTPUT': path + f'result/final.gpkg',
    'PRECISION': 5,
    'TAILLE': 15,
    'TYPE': 1
}
processing.run('Networks:update_field', alg_params)
```

The extension is available and can be downloaded here -> https://urlz.fr/pyJH

The "processing.run('Networks:update_field', alg_params)" code is pasted from the QGIS model builder, I don't think I'm wrong with the syntax.

Does anyone have any clues to give me?

Comment: You will need to add the custom processing provider to the processing registry. See [Using custom Processing algorithm from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408684/using-custom-processing-algorithm-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui). Probably you will also need to add the path to the location of the custom provider module (e.g. the custom plugin's folder) to `sys.path`.