Applying also the labels, assigning a .qml style file to a layer with PyQGIS
I'm working on QGIS 3.36 and I'd like to apply a .qml style file to a layer. Writing the following instructions of my code, the aspect of layer changes as I want it, but it doesn't load the labels stored inside the same .qml file. Why? Here my code:

barreTerr = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3003", "ioTerr", "memory")
barreEd = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3003", "numEdifici", "memory")
struttura = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3003", "grafico", "memory")

dpE = barreEd.dataProvider()
dp = barreTerr.dataProvider()
        
dp.addAttributes([QgsField("Tipo", QVariant.String)])
dp.addAttributes([QgsField("anno", QVariant.String)])
dp.addAttributes([QgsField("Io", QVariant.Double)])
dp.addAttributes([QgsField("numTerr", QVariant.Int)])
dpE.addAttributes([QgsField("anno", QVariant.String)])
dpE.addAttributes([QgsField("NumEdifici", QVariant.Int)])
barreTer.updateFields()
barreEd.updateFields()
requestTerr = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()
criterioTerr = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('Anno', ascending=True)
        
orderbyTerr = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([criterioTerr])
 
requestTerr.setOrderBy(orderbyTerr)
        
featuresTerr = layerTerremoti.getFeatures(requestTerr)
  
elementiTerr = [fgt for fgt in featuresTerr]
barreTerr.loadNamedStyle('c:/Users/Salvo/Desktop/LayerGIS/stile_graficiTerr.qml')
struttura.loadNamedStyle('c:/Users/Salvo/Desktop/LayerGIS/etichette_grafico.qml')
barreEd.loadNamedStyle('c:/Users/Salvo/Desktop/LayerGIS/stile_numEdifici.qml')
barreTerr.triggerRepaint()
struttura.triggerRepaint()
barreEd.triggerRepaint()
for feat in elementiTerr:
            
    if (feat['Year'] >= aI) and (feat['Year'] <= aF):
                
         if feat['IoNum'] != NULL:
             io = QgsFeature(barreTerr.fields())
             annoPunto = QgsFeature(layerAnni.fields())
                 if feat['Year'] == aI:
                        lagIniziale = 0.3
                 inizioCalcoloposizioneAnno = (feat['Year'] - aI )
            
                 posizioneAnnoDef = (inizioCalcoloposizioneAnno +lagIniziale) / (aF - aI) * dimX
                   
                    
                 calcoloIo = feat['IoNum'] / ioMax
                 ioPosizione = calcoloIo * dimY
                    
                    
                 if feat['Year'] != annoCorrente:
                     stack = 0
                        
                     rep = 1
                     
                     
                        io.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(posizioneAnnoDef, 0),QgsPointXY(posizioneAnnoDef,ioPosizione)]))
                        
                 else: 

                        rep = rep + 1
           
                                                                              io.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(posizioneAnnoDef, stack), QgsPointXY(posizioneAnnoDef,                                              stack + ioPosizione)]))
                        
                        
                    
                io.setAttributes(["Terr", feat['Year'], feat['IoNum'], rep])
                dp.addFeature(io)
                stack = stack + ioPosizione
                lagIniziale = 0
                
                annoCorrente = feat['Year']
                ioPosizione = 0
                listaIoTerr.append(io)

If I apply manually this .qml style file ("stile_graficiTerr.qml") the labels appear, but with the instruction inside the code the result is not the same and the labels disappear.
UPDATE : I updated the code, don't pay attention to indentation because in the real code is surely correct. The code works, except for the labels.

What is the layerAnni variable ?

I do not think we currently have enough information to answer this. Do you add any features to the created layers? Do those features have attributes in the added fields? What field/expression do you use for the labeling? The code you have presented simply shows that you are loading style files to empty memory layers with no features. Side notes: you should add calls to barreTerr.updateFields() & barreEd.updateFields() after adding the fields so that they are retrieved from the data provider...

...also you do not need to call addAttributes() for every field you add. You can make a single call per data provider and add multiple fields at once inside a single list. In any case, if you want a canonical answer here, I think you would probably need to provide a .qml file for testing and a minimal code snippet which actually reproduces the issue. I can only guess here, but the likely root cause is that the labeling field/expression settings in the .qml cannot be applied to the temporary layer because the field is missing, field names don't match or something like that.

If you can manually apply a .qml to a layer and get labels to appear, then either that layer must be a different one to those created in the code you show (which don't contain any features and could not be labeled) or there is some code which you have not shown where you add features and assign some attributes to those features (and indeed add the layers to a project or canvas). Perhaps you could update your question to explain the scenario a bit better.

Excuse me. I updated the code. The original code is very long and it works, except for the labels. Thank you for your help.

If you manually apply the desired qml layer using the QGIS interface, all style settings are applied correctly?

Yes. Just so...

I suggest you to use Set layer style tool for this task.
import processing
processing.run("native:setlayerstyle", {'INPUT':'layer', 'STYLE': r'С:\style.qml'})


If you are writing a standalone script - you can read about importing qgis libraries here or here.

"processing is not defined"

import processing ?

@SalvatoreDiolosà URL 1: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts URL 2: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/408684/35561
