# Connecting PostgreSQL/PostGIS registry in qgis.core.QgsProviderRegistry

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, standalone

I'm developing a standalone QGIS based Python script for loading layers from/to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. If I check the list using code:

```
providers = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
```

I'm getting only GDAL. I have tested with

```
print(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres'))
```

but it is giving **None**

My syste details are as follows:

```
OS:Windows 10 
QGIS:3.16.11
```

How can I include PostgreSQL extension in the `qgsProviderRegistry`?

Comment: Is your [QGIS prefix](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/layer-is-not-valid-error-in-my-standalone-pyqgis-script-app/155852#155852) well defined?

Comment: What is your OS? Windows, Mac, Linux? Version of your OS? Version of QGIS? Edit your question to add them, plz.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce with the following code (Python 3.16 on Linux)

```py
import sys
from qgis.core import (QgsApplication, QgsProviderRegistry)

app = QgsApplication([], True)
# On Linux, didn't need to set it so commented
# app.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS Brighton/apps/qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

providers = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
print(providers)
# above statement returns
# ['DB2', 'OAPIF', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'ows', 'postgres', 'postgresraster', 'spatialite', 'vectortile', 'virtual', 'wcs', 'wms']
```

It clearly seems related to your library path when loading standalone Python script.

Comment: If I ran above code I'm getting ['gdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'ogr', 'vectortile'].

Comment: What is the ouptut of `QgsProviderRegistry.instance().libraryDirectory().path()` ? within QGIS Python console? What is the value within your standalone script?

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old but there are no further discussions about this topic.

My setting is: qgis(-server) running in a container, local `conda create env qgis`.

I think its not related to the platform. In a conda env with qgis (3.30) I have the same redcuced provider list as stated in comments before.

I also tried to set the `setPrefixPath` to `env/qgis/share/qgis` or `env/qgis/lib` where the `*postgres*.so` is located but no luck.

Maybe it works if `env/qgis/lib` is added to `sys.path` initially, but untested.

So a solution can be to read the credentials from the layer by reading the qgs xml file with e.g. `xmltodict` and `psycopg2` to accesss the layer.

If processing algs should be used then the layer needs to be recreated as a `QgsVectorLayer` from the select query.

But the problem of missing postgres provider in the qgis package by installing with
`conda create env qgis`
remains.

**Update**

i wanted to use processing where i had to call `Processing.initialize()`. I did call it before `initQgis()`. As stated [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) the providers should load with that command. But if `Processing.initialize()` is called before not all providers, e.g. postgres are loaded.

Well in the docs it is stated after `initQgis()`:
Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
algorithms, etc.

that was not clear to me as i thought calling `Processing.initialize()` where processing providers `QgsProcessingProvider` are appended to `QgsApplication.processingRegistry()` does not affect `QgsApplication().initQgis()`.

```
import os
from qgis.core import QgsApplication,QgsProviderRegistry
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"

def run():
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    # # this does not work
    # Processing.initialize()
    qgs.initQgis()
    Processing.initialize()
    print("provider path: ", QgsProviderRegistry.instance().libraryDirectory().path())
    print("provider list: ",QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList())
run()
```