# When using QGIS.Processing what is the temp memory argument? QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT doesn't work

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, pyqgis

I am moving a QGIS model to PyQGIS to be able to run it as part of a bat file in OSGEO Shell.

It's working fine in QGIS and if the data in each stage is written to a on disk file but I can't write to memory so that each part of the model can use model memory outputs.

The whole code is below. This is the error I get when run in OSGEO4W shell.

```
G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Working>python3 2_Process_Mower_Data_Osgeo.py
'"Speed KmH"  < 30'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Working\2_Process_Mower_Data_Osgeo.py", line 136, in <module>
    Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length)
  File "G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Working\2_Process_Mower_Data_Osgeo.py", line 34, in Clean_Mower_Data
    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
NameError: name 'QgsProcessing' is not defined

G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Working>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I know we can have `'OUTPUT': 'memory'` then how do we get a particular version of it like I get

```
outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable'] = processing.run('native:createpointslayerfromtable', alg_params)
```

then use this in the next process as

```
alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable']['OUTPUT'],
```

**==== code base ===**

```
# create environment for qgis to run outside of the application as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/2891
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

import os, glob, re

in_dir=r'G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Input'
out_dir=r'G:\Projects\192_Mowing_Automated_Reporting\Working\Draft_Output'
os.chdir(in_dir)

def Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length):
    # Extract by expression
    outputs = {}
    max_speed_alg='\'"Speed KmH"  < '+ str(max_speed)+'\'' 
    print (max_speed_alg)
    alg_params = {
                'EXPRESSION': '"Speed KmH"  < '+ str(max_speed) +' AND"Ignition" = \'On\'',
                'INPUT': in_file,
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
                }
                
    outputs['ExtractByExpression']=processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params)
    print ('1_ExtractByExpression')

    # Create points layer from table
    alg_params = {
                'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT'],
                'MFIELD': '',
                'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
                'XFIELD': 'Longitude',
                'YFIELD': 'Latitude',
                'ZFIELD': '',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable'] = processing.run('native:createpointslayerfromtable', alg_params)
    print ('2_CreatePointsLayerFromTable')

    # Points to path
    alg_params = {
                'CLOSE_PATH': False,
                'GROUP_EXPRESSION': '',
                'INPUT': outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable']['OUTPUT'],
                'NATURAL_SORT': False,
                'ORDER_EXPRESSION': '',
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['PointsToPath'] = processing.run('native:pointstopath', alg_params)
    print ('3_PointsToPath')

    # Explode lines
    alg_params = {
                'INPUT': outputs['PointsToPath']['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['ExplodeLines'] = processing.run('native:explodelines', alg_params)
    print ('4_ExplodeLines')

    # Extract by expression
    alg_params = {
                'EXPRESSION': '$length <'+str(max_length),               
                'INPUT': outputs['ExplodeLines']['OUTPUT'],
                'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
            }
    outputs['ExtractByExpression2']=processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params)
    print ('5_Extracted')
    
    # Join attributes by location
    alg_params = {
        'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
        'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByExpression2']['OUTPUT'],
        'JOIN': outputs['CreatePointsLayerFromTable']['OUTPUT'],
        'JOIN_FIELDS': [''],
        'METHOD': 1,  # Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)
        'PREDICATE': [0],  # intersects
        'PREFIX': '',
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['JoinAttributesByLocation'] = processing.run('native:joinattributesbylocation', alg_params, )
    print ('6_Joined')


    # Refactor fields
    alg_params = {
        'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': '"Date Logged (AET (+10:00))"','length': 0,'name': 'Date Logged (AET (+10:00))','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Date Received (AET (+10:00))"','length': 0,'name': 'Date Received (AET (+10:00))','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Log Reason"','length': 0,'name': 'Log Reason','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Transmission Delay(s)"','length': 0,'name': 'Transmission Delay(s)','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Latitude"','length': 0,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Longitude"','length': 0,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"GPS Age"','length': 0,'name': 'GPS Age','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Speed KmH"','length': 0,'name': 'Speed KmH','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Used Speed Limit (KmH)"','length': 0,'name': 'Used Speed Limit (KmH)','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Speed Band"','length': 0,'name': 'Speed Band','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Speed Accuracy (KmH)"','length': 0,'name': 'Speed Accuracy (KmH)','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Heading Degrees"','length': 0,'name': 'Heading Degrees','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Altitude (m)"','length': 0,'name': 'Altitude (m)','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Position Accuracy (m)"','length': 0,'name': 'Position Accuracy (m)','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"PDOP Raw"','length': 0,'name': 'PDOP Raw','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Ignition"','length': 0,'name': 'Ignition','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Gps Status Fix OK"','length': 0,'name': 'Gps Status Fix OK','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Gps Status Fix 3D"','length': 0,'name': 'Gps Status Fix 3D','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Digital Inputs"','length': 0,'name': 'Digital Inputs','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Digital Outputs"','length': 0,'name': 'Digital Outputs','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Driver Id Type"','length': 0,'name': 'Driver Id Type','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Driver Id Data"','length': 0,'name': 'Driver Id Data','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Trip Type Code"','length': 0,'name': 'Trip Type Code','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Project Code"','length': 0,'name': 'Project Code','precision': 0,'type': 10}],
        'INPUT': outputs['JoinAttributesByLocation']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': out_file
    }
    outputs['RefactorFields'] = processing.run('native:refactorfields', alg_params)
    print ('7_Refactored')
#    
    # Fix geometries
    alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['RefactorFields']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
    #
    outputs['FixGeometries']=processing.run('native:fixgeometries', alg_params)
    print ('8_FixedGeometry')
    
    # Reproject layer
    alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['FixGeometries']['OUTPUT'],
            'OPERATION': '',
            'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:28355'),
            'OUTPUT': out_file
        }
    processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', alg_params)    
    print ('9_Reprojected')
    
filelist=glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in filelist:
    
    #Process with speed/length limits
    fn=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    max_speed=30
    max_length =150
    fn=s=re.findall("^DeviceDataExport_(.*)_.*",fn)
    fn=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', fn[0])+'__s'+str(max_speed)+'_l'+str(max_length)
    in_file=os.path.join(in_dir,file)
    out_file=out_dir+"//"+fn+".tab"
    Clean_Mower_Data(in_file,out_file, max_speed, max_length)
    print ('processed: %s --to--> %s' % (file, fn))
print ('Completed')
```

Comment: What if you simply add `QgsProcessing` to your list of imports from `qgis.core`? The error makes sense because you haven't actually imported the `QgsProcessing` class.

Comment: So simple, I assumed it was part of the `import processing` later on.

Comment: In fact I think it will also work if you just use the string 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' because the attribute `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` just returns a `QStringLiteral("TEMPORARY_OUTPUT")`  https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#a62584b5ed1558ebdf04a95d6f4a9d403

Comment: You could, but it is cleaner this way and safer against future changes. :)