# Load a shapefile using PyQGIS (QGIS 3.4) on ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to create a standalone application based on **QGIS API**. 
Here is my source code to load a `shapefile`:

```
import sys
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class MapViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, shapefile):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Map Viewer")

        canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        #canvas.useImageToRender(False)
        canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        canvas.show()

        layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, "layer1", "ogr")
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise IOError("Invalid shapefile")

        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
        # QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        # canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        # canvas.setLayerSet(layer)
        # canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        contents = QWidget()
        contents.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(contents)



# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin/qgis", True)

# create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
# algorithms, etc.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

viewer = MapViewer("/home/bot/STATE.shp")
viewer.show()

app.exec_()

# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the
# provider and layer registries from memory

qgs.exitQgis()
```

I have tried different `shapefiles` from different location but all of them raise exception of `Invalid shapefile`.

My **PYTHONPATH**:

```
/usr/share/qgis/python
```

Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./q_test.py", line 57, in
>   
>       viewer = MapViewer("/home/bot/STATE.shp")   File "./q_test.py", line 25, in **init**
>       raise IOError("Invalid shapefile") OSError: Invalid shapefile

Comment: what is `shapefile` value?

Comment: I am really new to GIS can you explain what do you mean by `value`?

Comment: shapefile is ,for example "C://my/shape/path.shp" ?

Comment: `/home/bot/STATE.shp`

Comment: ah ok, check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308406/49538

Comment: I fixed my path from here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142541/viewer-not-displaying-the-data-in-my-standalone-pyqgis-application/142548#142548 but I am getting a blank black screen can you help me with that?